# Multiple Images Select from Media storage from admin Panel

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

By Default magento when we select images from media storage it's select images One by One. Is their any way in which we can select multiple images at a time and assign images to product.

Please see the attached image for better understanding https://www.screencast.com/t/0EUcWFRQbP2E

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but I am talking about for selecting media images which are already uploaded on magento media section.Please see the attached image for better understanding 

https://www.screencast.com/t/0EUcWFRQbP2E

Answer (score 0):

You can go to

> Catalog -> Products -> Edit -> Images And Videos

Click on the `Browse Image`

> Use CTRL to select multiple Images

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but I am talking about for selecting media images which are already uploaded on magento media section. @mohit